# How to create rails alias command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have seen some developers used alias command for there projects. Like `rs` to run `rails server`.

1. How to create that `alias rs="rails server"`?
2. where to config that?
3. Is it works for window?
4. Is need any specific ruby or rails version?

Comment: If you are using ubutu refer http://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias

Answer (score 0):

It's about shell and not about rails. You can create alias to all commands you want. Those aliases are created on your profile like `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` for example. Then to use aliases you need to study about them on documentation of shell you are using. On Windows I think Powershell supports aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put that command into a file (unless you want it to persist into the next session. To test what will work for you just put it in your terminal:

alias rs="rails server"

Then type rs. If it works you need alias, if not continue reading for doskey macros.

Now for windows, if you are running cygwin or a linux virtual machine, you use ALIAS. If you are using the Windows shell you ise DOSKEY.

```
doskey alias_name="some command here"

alias alias_name="some command here"
```

If you are on windows or 8 it doesn't like files without extensions. To create a .bashrc file, create a .bashrc. (notice the trailing .) and Windows will remove the last dot.